# How can I remove or disable some initialization from NSView class in my sub?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I want remove `(frame: )` and `(coder: )` initialization from my sub class coming from my NSView super class, I tried this code but I was unable to do it, how can I make my sub just be initialized with `init()`? I have to say I tried to use `override` but it seems cannot help me to reach my goal of having just `init()` as initialization.

```
class MyNSView: NSView {
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't remove it.

`init(frame:` is the designated initializer of `NSView`

As `convenience` initializer you **have to** call it – on `self`, not on `super`

```
class MyNSView: NSView {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

However if the view is designed in Interface Builder then `init(coder` will be called.

Comment: If `init(frame:` is the designated initializer of NSView, why I can use `let myView = NSView()`? I mean if apple api needs a frame so badly that they made it designated or required one, what is the point of having `init()` as option in NSView class?

Comment: Good question. I think the API exists long before AutoLayout came in, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `required` keyword while implementing the `init()` method.

```
class MyNSView: NSView {
    required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

You'll be able to initialize instances of your class by simply using

```
let myView = MyNSView()
```

Comment: Thanks, the goal of question is to remove (frame: ) and (coder: ) initialization from my sub class, it does not mean I do not want use them internally from the super, it means my sub class can be initialized just with `init()`, and the other initialization should be unavailable for sub. Also I had no issue to initialization my sub class with `init()` in first place.